# How can i send parallel request in Android using Retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I use [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) in my Android client.

For example, When I make 2 requests and send the request, first request is sent directly. but, the second request is sent after first request get a response.

How can i send the two requests at the same time?

Comment: are you using `execute()` command to fire up your request? If yes use `enqueue(Callback responseCallback)`.

Comment: @Radix Thank you for your help.